# PHP - split String in Key/Value pairs

Tags: php, string, split, key-value

I have a string like this:

> key=value, key2=value2

and I would like to parse it into something like this:

```
array(
  "key" => "value",
  "key2" => "value2"
)
```

I could do something like

```
$parts = explode(",", $string)
$parts = array_map("trim", $parts);
foreach($parts as $currentPart)
{
    list($key, $value) = explode("=", $currentPart);
    $keyValues[$key] = $value;
}
```

But this seems ridiciulous. There must be some way to do this smarter with PHP right?

Comment: Where does your data come from? Do you control how it is stored? Is it supposed to be a human readable (and writable) format?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

If you don't mind using regex ...

```
$str = "key=value, key2=value2";
preg_match_all("/([^,= ]+)=([^,= ]+)/", $str, $r); 
$result = array_combine($r[1], $r[2]);
var_dump($result);
```

Comment: however... using explode and loop like in the OP example will more than likely prove to be more efficient than using regex to parse it.

Comment: You never know that before you benchmark it. It heavily depends on the usage pattern.

Comment: I just had to use this. You nailed it!

Comment: I have
$selectedSoftware = array("AntiVirus ($20)","Norton ($100)");
$n = implode(',',$selectedSoftware);
$bool = preg_match_all("/([^,]+) \(\$(\d+)\)/", $n, $matches);
and it returns 0

can't figure out why, i tested it here http://www.phpliveregex.com/p/by8

Answer (score 14):

```
<?php parse_str(str_replace(", ", "&", "key=value, key2=value2"), $array); ?>
```

Comment: Beware this breaks if key or value contains an ampersand (&)

Answer (score 11):

if you change your string to use `&` instead of `,` as the delimiter, you can use [`parse_str()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-str.php)

Answer (score 2):

If you can change the format of the string to conform to a URL query string (using `&` instead of `,`, among other things, you can use `parse_str`. Be sure to use the two parameter option.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a single command solution using `array_reduce` formatted in multple lines for readability:

```php
<?php
$str = "key=value, key2=value2";
$result = array_reduce(
   explode(',', $str), 
   function ($carry, $kvp) {
      list($key, $value)=explode('=', $kvp); 
      $carry[trim($key)]=trim($value); 
      return $carry;
    }, []);
```