# How would I turn this string into an array?

Tags: php, arrays

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [PHP - split String in Key/Value pairs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4923951/php-split-string-in-key-value-pairs)

Hey experts how would I turn this string into a usable array?

fname=first_name,lname=last_name,phone=phone_number,street1=address,city=city,state=state,zip=zip,carrier=carrier

Comment: I'm an *expat*, but *export* seems derogatory... :-?

Comment: expert, perhaps? Of course, experts are simply former drips under pressure.

Comment: @Mario I know it looks like the same question but I really don't want to use reg ex which is why I decided to ask how to do it without reg ex :)

Comment: @deceze LOL sorry I meant EXPERTS of course :)

Comment: @JeffLong Your question did not say so; apart from explode being the most flaky and long-winded of all options.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$arr = array();

$pieces = explode(",", $str);
foreach($pieces as $piece)
{
    list($key, $value) = explode('=', $piece);
    $arr[$key] = $value;
}
```

Comment: Worked beautifully and very clean thank you!

Answer (score 2):

```
array_map(function ($i) { return explode('=', $i); }, explode(',', $string))
```

Comment: This didn't seem to work but thanks for the effort

Comment: @Jeff Long: that's because you're using unsupported php version

Answer (score 1):

something along the lines of--
    foreach(split($long_str, ',') as $pair) {
       $pair_arr = split($pair, '=');
       $map[$pair[0]] = $pair[1];
    }

I'm sure the syntax is off, but it should give you the idea.

Answer (score 0):

```
$res = array();
for ($i in explode(',', $input)) {
    $parts = explode('=', $i);
    $res[$parts[0]] = $parts[1];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$chunks = explode(',', $string);
$arr = array();
foreach($chunks as $set)
{
    $kv = explode('=',$set);
    $arr[$kv[0]] = $kv[1];
}
```

That will give you:

```
$arr['fname'] = 'first_name';
$arr['lname'] = 'last_name';
$arr['phone'] = 'phone_number';
$arr['street1'] = 'address';
$arr['city'] = 'city';
$arr['state'] = 'state';
$arr['zip'] = 'zip';
$arr['carrier'] = 'carrier';
```

Here's php manual page on [explode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php).

Answer (score 0):

$str = "fname=first_name,lname=last_name,phone=phone_number,street1=address,city=city,state=state,zip=zip,carrier=carrier";

parse_str(str_replace(",", "&", $str), $result);

var_dump($result);

Answer (score 0):

```
/**
 * Converts a string to an associative array.
 *
 * Usage:
 * 
 * echo strToAssocArray("k=v,k2=v2", "=", ",");
 * // outputs array('k' => 'v', 'k2' => 'v2')
 *
 * @param string $str the string
 * @param string $keyValueSep the separator between key and value
 * @param string $recordSep the record separator
 * @return array the resulting associative array
 */
function strToAssocArray($str, $keyValueSep, $recordSep)
{
    $sep1 = preg_quote($keyValueSep);
    $sep2 = preg_quote($recordSep);
    $regex = '/(.*?)' . $sep1 . '(.*?)(?:' . $sep2 . '|$)/';
    preg_match_all($regex, $str, $matches);
    return array_combine($matches[1], $matches[2]);
}
```