# Extract keys from string containing multiple keys

Tags: php

I'm searching for a way to easly extract a string containing multiple keys. The string is a result form a curl header response

```
echo $response['body'];
// status=2 reason=Invalid tariff/currency
```

Desired result:

```
$status == '2';
$reason == 'Invalid tariff/currency';
```

or

```
array (
    [status] => '2'
    [reason] => 'Invalid tariff/currency'
)
```

Comment: It really depends on how well you can predict the form of that data... For example, if the key-value pairs are always separated by a space and are assigned using the equals operator, then a simple preg_match should parse them out.

Comment: links http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4923951/php-split-string-in-key-value-pairs           http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-str.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this, perhaps?

```
$parts = explode(" ", $response['body'], 2);
foreach($parts as $part)
{
   $tmp = explode("=", $part);
   $data[$tmp[0]] = $tmp[1];
}

var_dump($data);
```

Answer (score 0):

Given the string above, you can create local variables `$status` and `$reason` using [PHP Variable variables](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php). Take a look at this code:

```
$str = 'status=2 reason=Invalid tariff/currency';

foreach (explode(' ', $str, 2) as $item) {
    list($key, $val) = explode('=', $item);
    $$key = $val;
}

// Now you have these
echo $status;  // 2
echo $reason;  // Invalid tariff/currency
```

Answer (score 0):

try this, it will work only for your example, I suggest better to go with preg_match if you have possibility of extracting data from different formats.

```
$response['body'] = "status=2 reason=Invalid tariff/currency";
$responseArray = explode(" ", $response['body'], 2);
foreach($responseArray as $key => $value){
    $requiredOutput = explode("=",$value);
    print_r($requiredOutput);
}
```