# Php Complex Exploding

Tags: php, arrays, explode

Here is a string..

```
$string = "foo1 : bar1, foo2: bar2, foo3: bar3";
```

Exploding using `,` delimeter

```
$exploded = (",", $string);
```

Now the `$exploded` array contains:

`foo1 : bar1`
`foo2 : bar2`
`foo3 : bar3`

Now I need to put `foo1` in an `array['key']` and `bar1` in `array['value']`

How to achieve this?

Comment: this looks like you are parsing _sort-of_ json - are you?

Comment: JSON is a bit more complicated. There would be quotes for `bar` values.

Comment: @AD7six nop nop its from the database

Comment: @YousufMemon you may be asking the wrong question - why are you storing a string like that in your db? If you're going to store a serialized structure in the db, then actually store a [serialized](http://php.net/manual/es/function.serialize.php) [structure](http://es1.php.net/manual/es/function.json-encode.php) in the db - and use the inverse functions to extract your arrays.

Comment: @AD7six I am storing the database of cellphones in a table. Nowadays cellphones comes with new specifications so I just made a column named ``others`` in the database which will store a new name of specificaiton and its value in this ``foo1 : bar1, foo2: bar2, foo3: bar3`` format.

Comment: IMO you're doing it wrong. Use [EAV](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity%E2%80%93attribute%E2%80%93value_model) or at least an established format for your other properties. Not a custom storage format, with custom code to write it, and custom code to read/parse it. E.g. what happens if the key/value you want to store contains the string " : " or a comma etc.

Comment: Database is determined to save organised data into separate columns - Ergo: you **needn't** and **shouldn't** create own ways to divide data in database. Instead, create necessary database structure.

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP - split String in Key/Value pairs](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4923951/php-split-string-in-key-value-pairs)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll need to create another loop to go through an array of `"foo:bar"` strings and explode them:

```
$exploded = explode(",", $input);  
$output = array();       //Array to put the results in
foreach($exploded as $item) {  //Go through "fooX : barX" pairs
  $item = explode(" : ", $item); //create ["fooX", "barX"]
  $output[$item[0]] = $item[1];  //$output["fooX"] = "barX";
}
print_R($output);
```

Note that if the same key appears more than once in the input string - they will overwrite each other and only the last value will exist in the result.