# how can I split a string with different delimiters into an array?

Tags: php, arrays, string

How can I split a string with different delimiters into an array?

i.e. convert this: 'web:427;French:435' to this:

```
'web' => 427,
'french' => 435
```

Comment: What counts as a delimiter?

Comment: With a regex or `strtr` and `parse_str`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mario pointed out, if you don't mind using regex you can amend [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4924004/1645769) to fit your needs. If you wish to do it without regex try this: (will work as long as your string doesn't have `:` and `;` inside the variable names or values)

```
$str = 'web:427;French:435';
$array = explode(';',$str); // first explode by semicolon to saparate the variables

$result = array();
foreach($array as $key=>$value){
    $temp = explode(':',$value); // explode each variable by colon to get name and value
    $array[$temp[0]]= $temp[1];
}

print_r($result);
```

Answer (score 1):

This will work as long as your string does not contain `&` or `=`.

```
$str = 'web:427;French:435';
$str = str_replace([';', ':'], ['&', '='], $str);
parse_str($str, $array);
print_r($array);
```