# Double explode string

Tags: php, arrays, explode

Given is a string with two different delimiters:

`$string = '123|foo,456|bar,789|bla';`

Result should be an array:

```
array
(
    [123] => 'foo'
    [456] => 'bar'
    [789] => 'bla'
)
```

Or:

```
array
(
    [0] => array
           (
               [id] => 123
               [value] => 'foo'
           )
    [1] => array
           (
               [id] => 456
               [value] => 'bar'
           )
    [2] => array
           (
               [id] => 789
               [value] => 'bla'
           )
)
```

What would be the smartest way to explode the string and bring it into the arrays?

Comment: explode on comma and then on | ? have you used the explode function ?

Comment: explode on comma, loop, explode on bar

Comment: You mentioned the solution - `explode()` - in your question title.

Comment: possible duplicate of [how can I split a string with different delimiters into an array?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17936012/how-can-i-split-a-string-with-different-delimiters-into-an-array)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can try something like this:

```
$string = '123|foo,456|bar,789|bla';

$output = array();
foreach(explode(',', $string) as $pair) {
    list($id, $val) = explode('|', $pair);
    $output[(int) $id] = $val;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

As an alternate to the inevitably suggested double-explode.  If you know that you have a well-formed input string (i.e. no `=` or `&` in key-value pairs) you could try this:

```
$string = '123|foo,456|bar,789|bla';
$array = array();
$search = array('|', ',');
$replace = array('=', '&');

parse_str(str_replace($search, $replace, $string), $array);

var_dump($array);
```

What is happening is that you are making string replacements to make your string look like a query string.  You then [`parse_str()`](http://php.net/parse_str) it's values into `$array`.

Comment: Could this be faster than multiple explodes for big data?

Comment: @kingkero Not sure. I would think it possibly could since you would be eliminating the looping structure in favor of using the natively implemented parsing instruction.  I would also think this would require less memory than having multiple array holding the data (one for looping one for storage).  Of course one would need to test to determine for sure.

Answer (score 1):

```
$string = '123|foo,456|bar,789|bla';
$array = explode(",", $string);
$result = Array();
foreach ($array as $data){
    $temp = explode("|", $data);
    $result[$temp[0]] = $temp[1];
}
print_r($result);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
You can use this one which returns an array like your second one
<?php
$string = '123|foo,456|bar,789|bla';
$str_arr = explode(',', $string);
$result = array();
foreach($str_arr as $data) {
    list($id, $val) = explode('|', $data);
    $result[] = array("id"=>$id,'value'=>$val);
}
print_r($result);
?>
```